# How to interpret C++ left-associativity logic in a strict technical sense?

Tags: c++

New to C++ and am currently reading "Accelerated C++" (Koenig & Moo) but struggling to understand the logic of left-associativity in one particular section. Specifically, on p.62, the expression:

`is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;`

Evaluates

`( is >> s.name >> s.midterm ) >> s.final;`

That is, the first term inside `()` reads-into the second `s.final`. However, `is` characters stream into each `s.name`, `s.midterm` and `s.final` variables independently - how can this be? Am I confusing operations (relational against arithmetic) or how do I interpret this directional flow of information in a strict technical sense?

Comment: It is evaluated more like `( ( ( is >> s.name ) >> s.midterm ) >> s.final );` instead. And from a technical standpoint, it is actually chaining the calls like this: `operator>>(operator>>(operator>>(is, s.name), s.midterm), s.final);` or maybe `operator>>(is, s.name).operator>>(s.midterm).operator>>(s.final)` depending on the actual types of the fields. `operator>>` returns a reference to the stream object, so the next `operator>>` can be called on it. Some operators are implemented directly as members of the `istream` class and others are implemented as free-standing functions instead.

Comment: Thank you, @Remy. Operand types effect call chainings?

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner, no, but there are both free and member functions named `operator>>`.

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt, etc

Comment: Thank you @Enlico. This is an awesome language and very different to the others I know/use.

Comment: Thank you for the resource, @RemyLebeau. Adding to resources.

Comment: It seems to me that a key piece here is the value of `( is >> s.name >> s.midterm )`. What do you believe this expression evaluates to?

Comment: Hi @JaMiT. Evaluation: `( is >> s.name ) >> s.midterm )` ; or descriptively the object `is` belonging to the `std` library reads-into string `s.name` a stream of characters input by the user, which are then in-turn used to identify the string to be read-into `s.midterm`. Is that close at all?

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner You described side-effects rather than value. *Ex: `std::vector::insert` has the side-effect of inserting, but its value is an iterator.* Breaking `( is >> s.name >> s.midterm )` down into `( (is >> s.name) >> s.midterm )` is a good start. Next, evaluate each piece, not list the side-effects. *What I'm going for is more along the lines of `is >> s.name` evaluates to `is`, then `is >> s.midterm` also evaluates to `is`.*  (Also, the object does not belong the the standard library. Its *class*, though, either belongs to the standard library or derives from something that does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to the language I think a good interpretation for `is >> x` is as follows:

- `is` is an object capable of using low level functions to request an input from the keyboard (or another device, including a file)
- the `<<` operator is the one to which you can feed `is` and `x` so that `is` does it's job and puts in `x` what it reads from the device
- the value returned by the expression `is >> x` is essentially of the same nature as `is`, and can be used again in the same way.

As regards the 3rd point, refer to [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) on `operator<<`/`operator>>` for `std::basic_string`: you'll see that the signature is the following (cleaning it up from things not relevant to the question)

```
template <class CharT>
std::basic_istream<CharT>&
    operator>>(std::basic_istream<CharT>& is,
               std::basic_string<CharT>& str);
```

where it's clear that `operator>>` returns an object of the same type as its first input, i.e. the expression `is >> x`, after having the side effect of reading stuff from device and altering the value of `x`, eventually evaluates to an object of the same type as `is`.

---

If you really want to go deep into this, you can write this simple code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int x;
  std::string y;
  std::cin >> x >> y;
}
```

and, with the help of your IDE, jump to the two `>>`s to explore what they do or look like. Among other things, you'll find out that

- the first `>>` will result in a call to `basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(int& __n)`, which is a member function of the class `basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>` and returns and object of that class by reference, `basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&`. What is the object on which `???.operator>>` is called? Well, it's obviously [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin). And what is the object that the call returns? Go to the bottom of that function and you'll find `return *this;`, so it returns `std::cin` itself, possibly modified in the body of the function;
- the second `>>` results in a call to `std::operator>>(basic_istream<char>& __is, basic_string<char>& __str);`, which is a free function in the `std` namespace. This, unlike the previous one, explicitly takes a first argument of type `basic_istream<char>` (which in our example is the expression `(std::cin >> x)`, but like the previous one returns a reference to the stream, `basic_istream<char>&`, which is still an altered version of `std::cin`, ready to be used again.

---

To address this comment of yours:

> reads-into string `s.name` a stream of characters input by the user, which are then in-turn used to identify the string to be read-into `s.midterm`

When you see `(is >> x) >> y`, the fact that "`is` reads stuff from input and puts it in `x`" is a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) (yeah, the side effect is the main reason why we are doing this, but it's still a side effect); the non side effect is that `is >> x` takes `is` and `x` into input and gives you back an object of the same type of `is`.

In `(is >> x) >> y`, the `x` does influence what can be read in `y`, but only in the sense that `is >> x` doesn't give you back exactly `is` but an altered version of it.

The first alteration is that whatever you have read into `x`, if `x` was, say, a `int`, `char *`, or whatever, can't be read again, so it's not available for `y`.

Another alteration, is that `x` might be some type of object that is merely used to alter `std::cin`. I don't have an example for this right now, but I have one for `std::cout`: in `std::cout << std::boolalpha << true;` the effect of the first `<<` is to take `std::cout` and give you back something which will print `true`/`false` instead of `1`/`0` when you feed it with a `bool`.

Comment: Note that `oprator<<` i.e. stream insertion is an operation supported by output streams, while `is` is presumably an input stream based on the name.

Comment: `std::boolalpha` applies to both directions of streams, you can `bool b; std::stringstream("true") >> std::boolalpha >> b;`